# Draggable Linked Boxes in GTK

Tags: user-interface, gtk, draggable

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how I might go about creating an interface with GTK that would enable me to draw boxes in a window that are linked together with lines and draggable. I'm trying to achieve essentially what you see in this screenshot of MySQL Workbench: http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/Article-Images/workbench-article-image1.png. Are there certain widgets built into GTK I can use or do I need to create custom widgets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [GooCanvas](https://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas). GTK itself doesn't have that kind of widget.